# Adding a SQL View Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

As I add a View to SQL Server I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'
```

because I have to Declare first a tempTable `Currency` then insert some values in it from `Currecy` then retrieved it and `Join` it to `Items` table where the `Select` Statement start

My Question is, does Creating a view disallows the creating of
TempTable or Inserting ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: no DECLARE in views... Please post what you did before. A CTE will probably help you... EDIT: a VIEW is only a "view"...

Comment: my first SQLQuery was 
I. Declare TempTable(YearMonth,Currency,Rate) 
II. then Inserted into TempTable select ForexTable
III. then Joined the Select statement with the tempTable

Comment: my second query which the SSMS accepted 
I. Joined the Select statement then joined the Forex Table
, I used TempTable for speed purpose, then for clean coding, so that it will be easy in joining

Comment: Hi, glad you found a solution! Just to keep this clear: A view is **one single call**. You cannot define several single statements (like declare, fill temp table etc.)

Comment: yep, thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server defines CREATE VIEW as following:

```
CREATE VIEW [ schema_name . ] view_name [ (column [ ,...n ] ) ] 
[ WITH <view_attribute> [ ,...n ] ] 
AS select_statement 
...
```

That means after AS you have to use a single select statement.
If you like, you can use various techniques to avoid filling your temporary table. CTE is a relatively simple technique that can ACT like a temp table.

So, instead of this:

```
select * 
into #tmp_currency
from Currency

...(alter table #tmp_currency)...

select * 
from 
    othertable ot
    join #tmp_currency tc
        on tc.your_pk_col= ot.your_fk_col
```

...you can use this...

```
;with tmp_currency as (
  select
    *,
    new_col = (whatever value you want to calculate)
  from Currency)
select * 
from 
    othertable ot
    join tmp_currency tc
        on tc.your_pk_col= ot.your_fk_col
```

View creation is then a trivial task:

```
create view yourviewname as
with tmp_currency as (
  select
    *,
    new_col = (whatever value you want to calculate)
  from Currency)
select * 
from 
    othertable ot
    join tmp_currency tc
        on tc.your_pk_col= ot.your_fk_col
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the really long response @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric , I have already solved it , Yep, I cannot use Temp Table or inserting to a Temp Table, all I did was just Joining the Table- the one I wanted to be in TempTable, and the result was the same,.. And It was my first time encountering 'CTE' ... thanks a lot guys (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Views do not allow creation of temporary tables. You need to use a Stored procedure

Comment: This depends on the needs. A Stored Procedure just to collect data is bad practice IMO. Most "I need some declares first" can be solved via CTE...

Comment: thanks a lot for the response @Madhivanan , Thank God , I solve it, yep, I cannot use Temp Table , what I did is just 'JOIN' it

Answer (score 0):

Yes a view is just a single select statement - it may contain CTEs or derived tables though.

If you do actually need procedural logic that can't be satisfied by those then you can use a multistatement table valued function.

Comment: Inserts in temp-tables aren't allowed there either... But anyway one should avoid that..

Comment: @Shnugo - But table variables are.

Comment: Yes, I know, but in this case I'd go with an inline-UDF and CTE. Much better performance!

Comment: @Shnugo -  Inline TVFs are just like views they don't allow any procedural logic either. I would use an inline alternative too if it does what is required. We don't know what the requirement is though so presenting both options.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response @Martin Smith , Thank God , I solve it, yep, I cannot use Temp Table , what I did is just 'JOIN' it